# How can we use/integrate keycloak in web application that is built on Java 6, Spring 3.0 and WebSphare Portal 6.1 and LDAP?

Tags: keycloak

We have an existing web applications that uses jdk6, ldap, spring 3.0, Oracle 12c and running on WebSphare Portal 6.1 server.

I have to integrate Keycloak as SSO for our existing web application so please suggest which version of keycloak can be used or supports above mentioned tech stacks?

As I am new to the Keycloack so not able to find out how to start with

Comment: Your first concern should be upgrading to Java 17 / 19 and Spring 6. How can one possibly additionally invest in so old versions (with all performance & security implications)?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Upgrading to Java 17/19 will not the only upgrade, we have to see for WebSphere Server upgrade as well. I was looking some solution as per the existing tech stacks(jdk6, ldap, spring 3.0, Oracle 12c and  WebSphare Portal 6.1 server).